# TemplateSyntaxError: 'with' expected with atleast one variable assignment

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to send the data of a **meeting** object from template to view via **GET** method. To give the attribute **meeting.date** a simpler alias i.e **date** I am using the **with** template tag. But it ends up with a TemplateSyntaxError.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^meeting/$', meeting_display, name="meeting"),
```

**views.py**

```
def meeting_display(request):
    date = request.GET.get('date')

    ob_mem = memo.objects.get(subject='Meeting', rcv_username=username, date=date)
    ob_mee = memo.meeting_set.all()

    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'meeting': ob_mee,
    })
    return render_to_response('meeting_display.html', variables)
```

**meeting_display.html**

```
{% for meeting in meeting_f %}
  <div class="list">
    {% with date = meeting.date %}
      <a href="{% url meeting %}?date={{date}}">{{ date }}:{{meeting.venue}}{{meeting.time}}</a>
    {% endwith %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There should be no spaces around `=`. Either use

```
{% with date=meeting.date %}
```

or [the old syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with):

```
{% with meeting.date as date %}
```

Comment: Silly me :| Thanks :)