# Django 3 Problem with concatenating inside a template tag

Tags: python, django, templates, django-template-filters

I want to concatenate a string inside a template in Django (version 3). I have read everything I could find on the subject and found that this should be the way:

```
{{ "ST" | add: item.id | stringformat:"08d" }}
```

But it produces the error:

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: add requires 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

Can anybody shed light into my darkness?

Comment: could you post back your expectation in the HTML

Comment: and also could you try this `{% "ST" | add:item.id | stringformat: "08d" as template %}
{% include template %} {% endwith %}`

Comment: If the id (pk) of the record in the database would be 17 the resulting HTML would have to be "ST00000017".

Comment: You second suggestion results in the error: `django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 21: '"ST"', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?` The `{% endwith %}` suggests that there should be a `startwith` somewhere

Comment: sorry forgot to include with at the start
{% with "ST" | add:item.id | stringformat: "08d" as template %} {% include template %} {% endwith %}

Comment: That produces the error: `django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'with' expected at least one variable assignment`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212089/discussion-between-jaswanth-and-johannes).

Comment: The problem is that `item.pk` is not a string, but an int, hence adding the two will not work (and the Django template mechanism will fail silently).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Willem Van Onsum points out the id (pk) is an integer and has to be converted to a string before concatenating. Besides the spaces have to be removed for it to work. See: [TemplateSyntaxError: 'with' expected with atleast one variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231619/templatesyntaxerror-with-expected-with-atleast-one-variable-assignment)

Hence the solution is:

```
    {% with n=item.id|stringformat:"08d" %}
        {{ "ST"|add:n }}
    {% endwith %}
```

Also thanks to @jaswanth for his contribution.