# Create variable in Django template

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I have this in my template:

```
{% for category in menu_categories %}
  {% with menu_button = "menu_"{{category}} %}
      <button class="button {{menu_button}}" onclick="showItem(menu_button)">{{category}}</button>
  {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am trying to create a series of buttons with `class` name by iterating a queryset of model `categories`.
I create a variable `menu_button` so that I could systematically name them, and pass the name to a JavaScript function `showItem()`.

But I get the error `'with' expected at least one variable assignment`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, maybe you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231619/templatesyntaxerror-with-expected-with-atleast-one-variable-assignment

Comment: @aurajimenez Thanks. I have figured out a few syntax errors in my code based on your link.