# How do i specify a variable in side of django template file

Tags: python, django, variables, jinja2

So I am trying to declare a variable inside of my django templates file

```
{% with object = "{{object.id
}}" %}
{% for detail in details %}   

{% if detail.post.id == {{object}} %}
        {{detail.name}}
        {% endif %}


{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

I know that with is used to this job, but when i run this code it shows me this error: 'with' expected at least one variable assignment

Please help me. Thank You

Comment: remove the spaces around the equals

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231619/templatesyntaxerror-with-expected-with-atleast-one-variable-assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `post_id` is likely an `int` so you should specify `object` as `{% with object=2 %}`, you furthermore should not use double curly brackets in a template tag:

```
{% with object=2 %}
  {% for detail in details %}
    {% if detail.post_id == object %}
      {{ detail.name }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

It is however not a good idea to filter in the template, since this is not efficient, and requires more memory, normally you filter in the *view*.

Comment: {% with object=2 %} having spaces result in ->  expected at least one variable assignment

Comment: this helped me declare a variable, however this is a detail view template, and i want to load the detail object.id and pass it into the template so only details of objects containing a certain id show up

Comment: @Flamiooo: normally, you do this with `object.detail_set`, or something similar where you query the releation in reverse, or you filter the details in the view, but doing this in the template is really not a good idea: templates are not very efficient, it will also require loading *all* details, which after a while can contain millions of records, and it would also require a lot of memory.

Comment: can you please tell me with an example how can I do so in the view because as you the template is not very efficient

Comment: @Flamiooo: I suggest you ask a new question where you share the view you are working with.

Comment: but how will get you to answer, should I like tag you init or something, I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: You do not tag people to answer your questions, you just ask a question and someone might answer