# Django-is it possible to use template filters inside "with"?

Tags: python, django, database, django-templates

I have a template filter called "get_data_id" that returns a value; I want to use that value as an argument for another filter called "get_data":

```
{% with variable_v= "x|get_data_id"  %}
    <p> {{ variable_v|get_data }} </p>
{% endwith %}
```

But django returns:

```
'with' expected at least one variable assignment
```

Is it possible to use template filters in "with clause" ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65782298/how-do-i-specify-a-variable-in-side-of-django-template-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a wrong Synaxis.
In your case:

```
{% with variable_v=x|get_data_id %}
    <p> {{ variable_v|get_data }} </p>
{% endwith %}
```

Bug is - use space_letter around "=" in with clause, next bug is - use string `"x|get_data_id"` instead of variable and filter `x|get_data_id`.